# Post message on Facebook wall from Sencha touch

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to post a message on Facebook wall...
Login popup came but login button press it show a error 'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.'
I cann't resolve this and i don't know how to post message to wall and close that popup...
Any can one please help me...
this is my code for post

```
                                FB.login(function()
                                {
                                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!'});
                                 },
                                {
                                    scope: 'publish_actions'
                                }),

                            function(response)
                            {
                                if (response && response.post_id) {
                                    alert('Post was published.');
                                } else {
                                    alert('Post was not published.');
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the site url and app domain. 
In app details ,in settings add platform, then select website,
 mentione website url as `"http://localhost:1200/" and domain as "localhost"`

```
 FB.ui(
                            {

                                method: 'stream.publish',
                                message: '',
                                attachment: {
                                    name: 'Name',
                                    //caption: 'Caption here.',
                                    description: (
                                        'description here'
                                        ),
                                    href: url
                                }

                                //user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                if (response && response.post_id) {
                                    alert('Post was published.');
                                } else {
                                    alert('Post was not published.');
                                }
                            }
                        );
```